# Could someone please help me understand how to choose a method for testing goodness of fit (model compared to measured data)?

Tags: chi-squared-test, goodness-of-fit, r-squared

I calculate models that describe measured data.  Most people in the field don't attempt anything statistical (the models have many potential sources of uncertainty).  However, I want to do a better job and see hints that expectations are changing. I can't find any resources (that are simple enough for me to understand) that answer my big-picture questions though.  Could someone please point me in the right direction?

Here's my situation.
I typically have (1) a set of measured data and (2) a model for describing the data.

As far as I know, I can't propagate uncertainties because my "measured data" are actually calculation results based on methods that can't be verified at certain conditions.  What I can do is evaluate "goodness of fit."

I felt proud of myself when I wrote down the "diagonal of covariance matrix (variance)" from something I found in Matlab, but my colleague doesn't understand what it is and doesn't think anyone else will either.  Also, the values look weird (some are negative).  My colleague thinks I should use "chi squared."

So I looked that up.  According to a description I found online, it is appropriate for "categorical" data. I'm a little iffy on what "categorical" means, but although I can divide my data and model results into categories (like measurements/model results at particular temperature), it seems like I don't have categorical data.  My data are a property, Z, at a temperature and another condition.

After all that, I'm thinking that I should be using "r squared."  Is this what people well-versed in statistics would expect to see in an evaluation of a model fit to measured data?  I have calculated it but don't understand what it means on a fundamental level.  I realize I'm asking a few broad questions but any tips would be very welcome as I'm feeling like I'm not getting any further on this.

Comment: Welcome to CV, @Ant. Categorical data is generally considered as discrete, (unordered) groups. Something like temperature is classified as "continuous", not a group, although it can be discretised. Before you start going to far down the road of "finding the right test", have you considered visualising the data vs model, e.g. a simple plot of x = measurement, y = model prediction? That will go far to tell you how your model differs from reality.

Comment: @AlexJ, thank you; that definition of categorical data (and explanation of where T fits in) is very helpful.  Yes, my colleague and I have been considering a plot of my model prediction versus the data.  We're arguing about how good the fit is.  That's why we'd like to find out if statistics can help us settle the argument!